# Kissing Spheres of Various Sizes (a plane of bubbles)

Tags: modeling, particles

How can I create something like the bubbles in this picture?

[image]

They are kissing (not fusing like soap bubbles do) so there should be no overlap.

Is there a way to achieve this with particles?

I envision starting by making a set of large and medium-sized bubbles and then adding a second set of small ones with collisions turned on -that way they should fill the gaps. Is this a good practice or is there a simpler method?

(The large misshapen bubbles are cool but can be ignored for this specific question.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Particles don't do collision with each other. You can duplicate a bunch of spheres and use rigid body physics to do collisions.

Comment: if you add one or more hair particle system to a plane -> render -> and select object and for "dupli object" add a sphere on another layer, and set the random size. But that wont give you that "kissing" effect. I don't have much experience with particles, maybe there is more you can do with them. Using a physics simulation would probably give you a better result easier. and soft bodies could be used for large bubbles to get deformation, but that could take time to get right. Hint: using proportional editing with random falloff and scale on individual origins to randomly scale many spheres at o

Answer (score 8):

This kind of bubble effect can be generated using rigid bodies and force fields. A mix of different size spheres are dropped on a plane and the force field causes them to pull together and space fill.

[image]

---

Procedure (tested on Blender 2.79)

1. Create the baseline geometry. Add a contained to drop the spheres into, add sphere of different sizes above the container. Set the contained as a passive rigid body. Set the spheres as active rigid bodies.
2. Add a force field actuator to the center of the container, under the floor. Set the force to a negative value to attract the spheres.
3. Set the gravity to a high number to pull all of the spheres to the floor and keep them there as they are pulled to the center.
4. Animate until everything is pulled together.

[image]

5. At this point, the spheres are reasonably packed and approximate the 'kissing spheres' stuck to a plane. Add the shaders and render.

---

Example Blender file - [image]