# How can you make a beer simulation Blender 2.83 (Mantaflow)?

Tags: fluid-simulation

I saw a lot of fluid simulations that look gorgeous thanks to the foam that Mantaflow adds, could you make a beer with foam simulation with it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make beer foam](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65500/how-to-make-beer-foam)

Comment: Not so much, I'm talking of an actual simulation, not a static photo